# Converting POLYHEDRALSURFACE to (MULTI)LINESTRING or POLYGON?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

99% of my table are MULTILINESTRINGs, but for some reason a few hundred are stored as POLYHEDRALSURFACE. How can I convert the following into MULTILINESTRING, LINESTRING, or POLYGON?

```
POLYHEDRALSURFACE(
    ((560239.265 5936001.262,560242.568 5936001.723,560242.568 5936001.723,560239.265 5936001.262,560239.265 5936001.262)),
    ((560242.568 5936001.723,560242.905 5935999.309,560242.905 5935999.309,560242.568 5936001.723,560242.568 5936001.723)),
    ((560242.905 5935999.309,560239.602 5935998.849,560239.602 5935998.849,560242.905 5935999.309,560242.905 5935999.309)),
    ((560239.602 5935998.849,560239.265 5936001.262,560239.265 5936001.262,560239.602 5935998.849,560239.602 5935998.849)),
    ((560239.602 5935998.849,560242.905 5935999.309,560242.568 5936001.723,560239.265 5936001.262,560239.602 5935998.849)),
    ((560239.265 5936001.262,560242.568 5936001.723,560242.905 5935999.309,560239.602 5935998.849,560239.265 5936001.262))
)
```

Comment: `ST_Dump` them into Polygons (faces)

Comment: Study why you have polyhedral surface geometries and if they are in your table on purpose. Dumping them into faces may be a workaround but skipping them totally may work as well if you do not even know what those geometries are presenting.